# Prevent Redirecting for specific REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have added a directory to the public folder of my site and placed the following .htaccess file inside it:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user
```

The `.htpasswd` file exists and has valid content.

Within the site's the public folder, there is an .htaccess file with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

With this setup, my `/protected` folder is not protected.

- If I leave the rewrite rule untouched, Apache doesn't seem to read my `/protected/.htaccess` file, and my `/protected` folder is not protected.
- If I comment the rewrite out, attempted access to my `/protected` directory results in a password prompt, as expected.

I modified the root `.htaccess` rewrite rule with what I though should prevent `mod_rewrite` from attempting to rewrite requests to my `/protected` folder as below:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/protected
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But this seemed to have no effect:

- The request appears to be processed by `/index.php` instead of prompting for authentication details as expected
- `/protected` folder is not protected
- The rest of the site works normally

There is an `index.php` file inside my protected folder as well (`/protected/index.php`), with the following content:

```
die('protected');
```

Can anyone see a problem with this approach, or with my modifications to the root `.htaccess` rewrite rule?

Comment: So, is the content in `/protected` actually in that directory, or is is being handled by `/index.php`?

Comment: Ideally in `/index.php`, but I have placed a duplicated `/index.php` in `/protected/index.php`

Comment: Do you need to use `.htaccess`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I have no access to the `vhost` or any other apache config files.

Comment: Ok!  What did you mean by "requests are redirected" - are you actually getting a redirection response that changes the URL in your browser?

Comment: @ShaneMadden yes I see that I wasn't very clear there. There is no redirection response, what I mean (and should have said) is that the request seems to go straight through to the `/index.php` file, without the `/protected/.htaccess` file being touched. I've updated my question with this additional information.

Comment: That `!^/protected` condition seems to not be doing anything, then.  Is `/protected` the only thing in the path, or is there anything else, like `http://example.com/mysite/protected/`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden it's the only thing in the path, e.g. `http://staging.domain.co.nz/protected`

Comment: @ShaneMadden thank you for your help, the issue wasn't with my rewrite rules, see my answer for details.

Comment: Nice, good find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Facepalm*!

My rewrite conditions *do* work as expected, the issue was in my `/protected/.htaccess` file:

> For basic authentication, the server writes a "401 Unauthorized"
>   header and then looks for an error document based on a pre-defined
>   path. Most of the time, the error document won't exist in the
>   directory that you want to protect, so the request gets handled by the
>   rewrite engine which throws a 404 error.

The solution was to add the following to the `/protected/.htaccess` files:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
RewriteEngine off

... Authorisation lines
```

From [Conflict Between Apache URL Rewriting and Basic Authentication](http://www.myriadinteractive.com/blog/view/id/29/conflict-between-apache-url-rewriting-and-basic-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I just had this problem. You can also set the 401 errdoc in the main .htaccess if you don't want to or can't edit the protected .htaccess and you don't already have a 401 error document set.